# My website isn't working on Chrome but it is working fine on Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, ads

My website isn't working on Chrome but it is working fine on Mozilla after I added a script for displaying ads from Propeller Ads on my website.

The script is like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//go.oclasrv.com/apu.php?zoneid=XXXXXX'></script>
```

And the head tag for verification is:

```
<meta name="propeller" content="68aeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX75" />
```

I don't have adblock enabled. Is there any problem with the priority of loading of the scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the Chrome incognito window to see the changes in your website. Because in the normal window the browser is loading the cache.

Comment: yeah, it's working fine in incognito mode. But how to make it work on normal browser?

Comment: there is a cool feature in chrome (if you have the developer console open) -> right click your reload button and press "empty cache and hard reload"

Comment: go to chrome settings->show advance settings->clear browsing data

Comment: @httpNick yeah, that's okay. But what if the user of my website has to open it?

Comment: @VermaJr. I don't believe this would be a problem with the user seeing it, this seems to just be a problem with you seeing it because of your browser's cache.

Comment: @httpNick But I tried to access my website using my friend's device and the same thing happened.

Comment: @VermaJr Dont worry about it. They will see the changes.

Comment: There are other ways also, but for example, with PHP you can add a timestamp to the end of your resources, thus if the file has changed the user's browser will get it again `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js?<?= filemtime("main.js")?>"></script>`. Ofcourse this specific method requires that the file is on your own server.